# Use Eclipse classpath variable to replace absolute "sourcepath" path?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, classpath

I would like to use an Eclipse classpath variable to resolve the attached source JAR file for a library in my classpath. This is the contents of my current ".classpath" file in Elcipse (Indigo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/ApacheCommons/commons-logging.jar"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/Spring-WS/spring-ws-1.5.8-all.jar"/>

  <!-- [other entries] -->

  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

When I now add a source JAR file for "spring-ws-1.5.8-all.jar", the ".classpath" files contents is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/ApacheCommons/commons-logging.jar"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/Spring-WS/spring-ws-1.5.8-all.jar"
    sourcepath="D:/dev/sources/spring-ws-1.5.8-sources.jar"/>

  <!-- [other entries] -->

  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

As you can see, Eclipse added the "sourcepath" attribute to the "classpathentry" element with an absolute path.

Now my idea is to replace the absolute path with the classpath variable "SOURCE_PATH", which is correctly set to "D:/dev/sources".

(Please, don't ask why we have this setup or suggest we must change it; it is an old project and we are unfortunately not able/allowed to change the build structure).

I tried

```
sourcepath="SOURCE_PATH/spring-ws-1.5.8-sources.jar"
```

as well as

```
sourcepath="${SOURCE_PATH}/spring-ws-1.5.8-sources.jar"
```

but both variants do not work.

I seems, that I either use the wrong syntax or I don't understand the concept of classpath variables. Maybe the classpath variable can't be used for the "sourcepath" attribute?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I might not understand your question completely but it sounds like you added your jar file with an absolute path to begin with. Instead add it with a classpath variable.

Use the Project properties, select `Java Build Path` option. Then click on the `Libraries` tab. Then  `Add Variable....` If you haven't created your SOURCE_PATH classpath variable yet, you can do it from here by clicking the `Configure Variables...` button (just a shortcut to the proper workspace preference setting). Once configured you should see your SOURCE_PATH class path variable in the box at the top. You can click on it extend to `Extend...` it to a subfolder or a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Using Tod's answer above, if you have lots of jars in lots of projects, you may find it easier to edit the .classpath files directly.  Using a Java Build Path variable in .classpath changes the reference from:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/full/pathTo/Jar.jar"/>
```

to:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="NEW_PATH_VARIABLE/Jar.jar"/>
```

Comment: Can one use a path variable for kind="output" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [symbolic link](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Windows also supports paths starting with /.  This is drive dependent.  Try `cd /` on the Command Prompt to verify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that could be a solution, or more a workaround. But I rather would like to know the correct way of using those classpath variables.