# Adding external jar in classpath placed in home dir

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am working on a java project which consumes an external jar from another project. This external jar cannot be checked-in in lib folder as it evolves continuously. So we have planned to keep the latest jar inside a folder,say 'ExtJar', under User's Home dir. 
The question is how do I modify classpath to point to this jar from home dir? 
So, I was looking for something like and should work for all OS platforms-
classpathentry kind="lib" path="MyHomeDir/ExtJar/myExternalJar.jar"

where MyHomeDir is a variable I defined as per the link - 
 - [Use Eclipse classpath variable to replace absolute "sourcepath" path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268375/use-eclipse-classpath-variable-to-replace-absolute-sourcepath-path)

I looked into above link to add a variable but apart from this I also want this variable to point to appropriate home dir depending on OS, i.e C:\Users\\ExtJar\ for Windows OR /home//ExtJar for linux etc.

Is there any way to programatically modify value of this variable to point to home dir after evaluating which OS its being run on?

Comment: If the JAR "evolves continuously," how is the latest version expected to get into each developer's home directory?

Comment: We have a batch file which copies the latest jar file to the home dir. User has to run this batch file before he runs the java application.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I don't understand why you can't just check in the JAR with other JARs the project depends on. If it changes frequently, that's even more reason, in my opinion, to have it managed in version control. If you're not going to use a dependency management tool like Gradle or Maven, that's usually the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a Classpath Variable is that it's value is not the same for all workspaces; each workspace defines where the variable points to.

You can still use a Classpath Variable to solve your problem, though. For example, create a variable called `EXT_JAR_HOME` and point it to your `C:\Users\your.name\ExtJar` folder. Then in the project build path, use **Add Variable...** to select and **Extend...* it, selecting the actual JAR file. That will result in the project's build path having an entry like `EXT_JAR_HOME`/ExternalJar.jar`. Then each developer workspace will just need to, one time, define`EXT_JAR_HOME` and point it to the correct path. Linux users' actual location will look different than Windows users, obviously.

The point is, Classpath Variables must be defined in each workspace, that's how they're designed to work.

Comment: Thanks E-Riz for your answer. Actually I was confusing myself between classpath and buildpath. The external jar file has been defined as you said above in the classpath by adding a variable and extending it. So for each workspace will have to manually define it and that is acceptable solution for us. There was confusion as to what happens when we checkin new classses which references this external jar as they would give error if this jar is not checked in in the project. Now, since build path already has this external jar there will not be any compilation error with new checkins.